# Deciding whether a statement with mathematical expressions is true or false

Tags: logic

1. $2x-5=1$ if and only if $x=3$
2. If $x^2 \geq y^2$, then $x<0$ or $x \geq y$

I understand that for 1. we must prove the statement in both directions. That is:

If $2x-5=1$, then $x=3$

and

If $x=3$, then $2x-5=1$

But I don't understand (in both cases, 2. especially), how we can determine whether an expression such as $2x-5=1$ is true or false. For example, logical implication in the form of "If $P$, then $Q$" is true when both $P$ and $Q$ are true or $P$ is false. So, in the case of $2x-5=1$, is this true or false?

In the case of $x^2 \geq y^2$, is this true or false?

Am I understanding these statements incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $2x-5=1$. Then we can rearrange it as follows:

\begin{align*}
2x-5 &= 1 \\
\implies 2x &= 6 \\
\implies x &= 3.
\end{align*}

Moreover, if $x=3$, then $2x-5=2\cdot3-5=1$. Therefore $2x-5=1\iff x=3$.

Notice I never decided whether the statement $2x-5=1$ was actually true. I just showed the implication, that if it is true, then the statement $x=3$ is also true. This is how one proves implications in mathematics.

It turns out the statment "$2x-5=1$" is only sometimes true: what we have shown is that it is true exactly when "$x=3$" is true, and false otherwise.

For the second statement, we do not know whether or not $x^2\geq y^2$ is actually true, as it actually depends on the values of $x$ and $y$. What we can say though, is that if it is true, then:

\begin{align*}
x^2 &\geq y^2 \\
\implies x^2-y^2 &\geq 0 \\
\implies (x-y)(x+y) &\geq0
\end{align*}

At this point there are two possibilities: either both $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ are nonnegative, or one is nonpositive and the other is negative.

In the former case, $x-y\geq0\implies x\geq y$.

In the latter case, if one of $x+y$ and $x-y$ is nonpositive, and the other negative, then their sum is strictly negative, so
$$(x-y)+(x+y)=2x<0\implies x<0.$$

This proves the statement, that if $x^2\geq y^2$, then either $x<0$ or $x\geq y$. We still don't know whether the individual statements are inherently true, yet we can prove the implication regardless.